# CSS id selector not working with bootstrap despite CSS being loaded?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-selectors

I am using bootstrap to work with my website.

Of course there are instances when bootstrap may not be enough or lacks the flexibility.

In these cases we are going to want to use custom CSS.

However when I use my CSS it is not making any difference.

For example:

I have an image

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
.
.
.
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3858/screenshots/5909706/stackoverflow-design.png" id="foo">
    </div>
</div>
.
.
.
```

And I want to give that some styling so I load up my `main.css` and enter

```
#foo{
height: 400px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Yet my image does not change height or get a border-radius.

However if I do this and add my styling inline:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3858/screenshots/5909706/stackoverflow-design.png" id="foo" style="height:400px; border-radius:10px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

It works and all is good in the world.

Using a little bit of research it seems this problem is usually to do with either

a) Not being specific enough and thus the bootstrap styling is taking priority.

I don't see how this could be the case given I have given a unique id to my img tag `id="foo"`, how much more specific can I get?

or

b) not loading the css properly

This is how I am loading the css

**BASE.HTML**

```
...
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
...
```

I am quite new to CSS, what am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Today I have spent a few hours, unsuccessfully, trying to resolve this.

Here is what I have tried:

Using `!important` to see if it was an issue with the selector specificity. I added that and it still did not work.

Following on from that I did an inspect element on the item and I can see that it is recognising the tag and the css is being linked properly however it is still not working, in the styles menu it is only showing:

[image: styles]

of course there is no mention of my custom css only the stuff that I believe is the bootstrap styling.

the custom css is definitely being loaded as you can see here is my network details in chrome inspect showing status 200 on the main.css file.

**[image]**

I have spent several hours without any success.

Can anyone please help!!!!!

Comment: This is the correct way to ask a question. Also, do not insult other users, your questions will get closed and you will get banned. Have you tried something very simple like `body { background-color: red }` to see if your `main.css` is even being called? Also, if you view source on your page, and click on the main.css link, can you see the file contents? Is it maybe a browser cache issue?

Comment: Apologies. That outburst was not professional at all. I had not taken a break in coding for 12 hours and I have not left the house in 6 weeks again apologies. Now onto the coding. I did check and yes I think it could be with the browser because I clicked into the css file and it is showing what the file was earlier in the day for some reason? How can I get it to refresh everytime I open the page?

Comment: You can do a couple things to test the cache: add a query string to the file name like `main.css?v=2` this should force the browser to reload the file. Depending on what language you are using to output the the CSS link code, you could add the timestamp for the last time the CSS file was modified like `main.css?v=modifiedtime` (however you can generate that). PHP is easy to do that, not sure what you are using. Also, it's all good. I get coding for hours and getting frustrated. We're here to help you out :)

Comment: There are also commands to clear the cache on refresh: https://support.piktochart.com/article/243-clear-browser-cache

Comment: YES! That did the trick. I'm not too sure what you mean by the first part but doing the hard cache refresh in chrome works. I just need to do it each time I make a change to the main.css file. Anyway I can look into better ways in the future but this is workable for now. Thanks again friend. If you leave this comment as an answer? I can mark it as solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per answer request:

This appears to be a caching issue. You can circumvent the cache in a few ways:

## Hard Refresh

Do a hard refresh on your browser. Full instructions can be found here: https://support.piktochart.com/article/243-clear-browser-cache

But here are the main points:

**Windows/Linux: CHROME**

1. Hold down Ctrl and click the Reload button.
2. Or, Hold down Ctrl and press F5.
3. Open the Chrome Dev Tools by pressing F12. Once the chrome dev tools are open, just right click on the refresh button and a menu will drop down. This menu gives you the option of doing a hard refresh, or even clearing the cache and do a hard refresh automatically.

**Mac:**

1. Hold Shift and click the Reload button.
2. Or, hold down ⌘ (Cmd) and ⇧ (Shift) key and then press R.

**Windows/Linux (Mozilla Firefox and Related Browsers):**

1. Hold the Ctrl key and press the F5 key.
2. Or, hold down Ctrl and ⇧ (Shift) and then press R.

**Mac:**

1. Hold down the ⇧ (Shift) and click the Reload button.
2. Or, hold down ⌘ (Cmd) and ⇧ (Shift) and then press R.

**Internet Explorer:**

1. Hold the Ctrl key and press the F5 key.
2. Or, hold the Ctrl key and click the Refresh button.

## Disable the cache in your browser

As in Daniel Vitek's answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61218568/1172189), you can disable the cache using the Developer Tools in whatever browser you are using.

## Version your CSS file

Using this option, you can *usually* bypass cache by telling the browser to reload your CSS because there has been changes.

**Manually**

Add a query string to your CSS each time you update, e.g. `main.css?v=2` This will work, but requires you to update the version.

**Programmatically**
If you are using a server side language, a template system or even JS (the caveat is JS probably should load before your CSS file and not deferred), you can add the query string based on the modified date of the CSS. This will ensure the the CSS will only get reloaded when there was actually a change.

A PHP example would be using `filemtime()`. This gets the modified time of the file.

`main.css?v=<?php echo filemtime('main.css'); ?>`

That would print out the UNIX timestamp of when the file was last modified.